# Merge Two SSRS datasets output

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to create a tabular SSRS report using two datasets which build out of two different datasources. Challenge is that SSRS tables only accept one dataset at a time.

Please guide me how i can merge two datasets output two create a single tbulr report

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 has introduced a new function called “LOOKUP”. LOOKUP function is used to retrieve the value from multiple datasets based on 1 to 1 mapping. For example if we have two datasets and both the datasets have CustomerID so based on the CustomerID mapping, we can retrieve the data from both the datasets.

LOOKUP (Key value from already mapped dataset, Key value from new dataset, new value from new dataset)

You can read about the Lookup function [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)

Note: The granularity of the second dataset must match the first one.